# How to store a very large object in PostgreSQL using Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a very large(>1Gb) object in Django which I need to store in the PostgreSQL Database. I'm using Django's ORM for all the database operations. I'm always getting an error of the following form -

`django.db.utils.InternalError: invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824`

This is my existing code -

```
large_data = get_large_data()

self.objects.create(
    part_a=large_data["part_a"]
)
```

Is there a better way to pass this data to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [PostgreSQL docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F), there is a limit of 1Gb for columns